# Best way to create a Drafts List and save and Load entries from another list?

Tags: 2010, development, custom-list, draft

So, I have a Custom List named "Events". Now I'm searching for a best practice to create "drafts" for the list items of the list, because there might be some events (monthly/ annually) which have nearly the same contents as some in the future and I don't want to create the whole event again and again when I have to change e.g. just the title.

So I thought about another custom List called "event drafts" or something like that. It should be possible with a visual webpart to save new entries of the *Events* List (on button click) into the *event drafts* list. On creating a new Event in the *events* list (webpart is stored on top / below the newform.aspx), there should also be a dropdown menu to choose from the list items located in the *event drafts* list and when an item is chosen, the form should be filled with the content of the *event drafts* ListItem.

So that was my use-case, my questions are:

1. How do I realize such a "Save to event drafts"-Button? Is it possible to get the Values from the NewForm.aspx and save them to another list (which has the same columns, for sure)?
2. How do I realize the corresponding "Load from event drafts" - Button/dropdown?
3. Is there a better way to do it? I think it might be somewhat "over the top", creating a whole new list. Another way I thought of was something like "Add a button: "Save a copy as draft", which should save the actual Entries in the *Events* list and save a copy to the same list changing the event title to 'Draft: [EventTitle]' or something, but I don't like this solution for the events list would be blown up then.

I hope some of you might help me.

Best regards,
Dominik